# How to identify a string using a Hive Query

Tags: hive

I have a column which contains some free text description like:

```
BGA-S-02111 | Server not pingable
Site : abcds, hnikjge : KLETA0, Issue : Pipeline not working
```

I want to run a hive query that extracts **Server not pingable, pipeline not working string** to me from the entire sentence.

But i am not sure of how to extract it for all the data in the give column.

Comment: Both lines are in a single row or two rows ?

Comment: In different rows

Comment: add some more column. Both rows have same id ?

Comment: I have just two columns : 1. Id 2. Description - which contains above mention details. So the table is of the format    **Id**    **Description**    1  BGA-S-02111 | Server not pingable    2 Site : abcds, hnikjge : KLETA0, Issue : Pipeline not working